# Bootstrap - nearby images slider | adding text underneath

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap 3 to show the sides of images next to the main image.

What I'm wanting to do is add text underneath the center image.

Right now, in stead of going under the intended image (center) - it's added to above the next image as noted below:

I've tried using vertical aligns, clears and floats to no avail.

[image]

```css
 <style> .item img {
   max-width: 100%;
 }
 .item img:first-child,
 .item img:last-child {
   display: none;
 }
 /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
   .item img {
     float: left;
     width: 600px;
   }
   .item img:first-child,
   .item img:last-child {
     display: block;
   }
   .item.active {
     overflow: hidden;
     margin: 0 -546px;
   }
 }
 /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
   .item img {
     width: 600px;
   }
   .item.active {
     margin: 0 -434px;
   }
 }
 /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
   .item img {
     width: 600px;
   }
   .item.active {
     margin: 0 -330px;
   }
   </style>
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">


        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" />
        <p style="vertical-align:bottom">asdasdasdas</p>


        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0/fff" alt="" />



        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff00/fff" alt="" />

      </div>
      <div class="item">

        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0/fff" alt="" />
        <p style="overflow:visible">asdasdasdas</p>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff00/fff" alt="" />

        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/0000ff/fff" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">

        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff00/fff" alt="" />
        <p style="overflow:visible">asdasdasdas</p>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/0000ff/fff" alt="" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">

        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/0000ff/fff" alt="" />
        <p style="overflow:visible">asdasdasdas</p>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0/fff" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the text at the bottom of the div and then center it using CSS. You can also give the text left and right padding instead of centering it if you would rather have it justified to a side under the center image.

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/0000ff/fff" alt="" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0/fff" alt="" />
  <p class="words">Testing the words out.</p>
</div>

<style>
   .words{
      text-align:center;
   }
</style>
```

OR

```
<style>
   .words{
      padding-LEFT:WIDTH_OF_LEFT_IMAGE;
      padding-right:WIDTH_OF_RIGHT_IMAGE;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option for you is to wrap each `img` in a `div` and use `float: left`.

But if your text is not big you may just put it after all `img` and wrap with a `div.text-center`.

Check the first slide below:

```css
 <style> .item img {
   max-width: 100%;
 }
 .item img:first-child,
 .item img:last-child {
   display: none;
 }
 /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
   .item img {
     float: left;
     width: 600px;
   }
   .item img:first-child,
   .item img:last-child {
     display: block;
   }
   .item.active {
     overflow: hidden;
     margin: 0 -546px;
   }
 }
 /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
   .item img {
     width: 600px;
   }
   .item.active {
     margin: 0 -434px;
   }
 }
 /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
   .item img {
     width: 600px;
   }
   .item.active {
     margin: 0 -330px;
   }
   </style>
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">


        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" />


        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0/fff" alt="" />

        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff00/fff" alt="" />

        <div class="text-center">
            <p style="vertical-align:bottom">asdasdasdas</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="item">

        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0/fff" alt="" />
        <p style="overflow:visible">asdasdasdas</p>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff00/fff" alt="" />

        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/0000ff/fff" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">

        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff00/fff" alt="" />
        <p style="overflow:visible">asdasdasdas</p>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/0000ff/fff" alt="" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">

        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/0000ff/fff" alt="" />
        <p style="overflow:visible">asdasdasdas</p>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0/fff" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```